# How bregman divergence gives optimal solution for cluster assignment?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, distance

Can somebody gives intuition behind `Bregman divergences` that how using it leads to optimal cluster representation?

And why using `euclidean-distance`, which comes under `bregman divergence` is good than `cosine based` method? Even in high dims, cosine similarity gives better solution, because of bound between [-1,1], which is not the case for euclidean distance.

Comment: Your question does not make a lot of sense. I am not aware of any results that Bregman divergence is "optimal" (in what sense optimal?), and since Cosine and Euclidean are *both* Bregman divergences in a particular domain, they would then both be optimal anyway. And why would [-1,1] be better?

Comment: [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiOrLjt8_nfAhVQXn0KHeRzAiEQFjAAegQICRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fabs%2F1703.05175&usg=AOvVaw0W5Yexm-MtWZOE6HvL8Hvs) author is pointing that first two statement. Can you provide me right direction, where to read about it.

Comment: The statement there is different. It says equation (1) is optimal only for Bergman divergences; it's not the divergence that is optimal.

Comment: Sorry @Anony-Mousse for confusion. I also asked the same thing, how Bergman divergences gives optimal clusters i.e. (1)

Comment: No. That is the opposite. It's not optimal clusters, and it's not given by a Bregman divergence.

Answer (score 1):

The logic is the opposite direction.

Bergman divergence is not "optimal" (by what?) and does not give optimal clusters either.

What is **optimal is the arithmetic mean**: if you want to find the best representative *with respect to a Bregman divergence*, then this is the optimal (least squares) choice and not, e.g., the harmonic mean.

This assume you have already decided to use, e.g., squared Euclidean distance and L2 loss. It doesn't say this code was optional.